# Как узнать, входит ли конкретный ip в диапазон вида "2.0.0.0 - 2.15.255.255"

Tags: python, ip

Есть обычный ip и список диапазонов ip вида "2.0.0.0 - 2.15.255.255". Как определить входит ли ip в диапазон?

Comment: я бы первёл в число IP (как раз 32 бита) а дальше тупо сравнить что больше.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html В питоне есть для этого стандартная библиотека. (правда только в 3.х)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так, переводим в число, а дальше сравниваем уже как обычно.

```
def IP2Int(ip):
    o = map(int, ip.split('.'))
    return 0x1000000 * o[0] + 0x10000 * o[1] + 0x100 * o[2] + o[3]

MinD = IP2Int('2.0.0.0')
MaxD = IP2Int('2.15.255.255')
TGood= IP2Int('2.10.255.255')
TBad = IP2Int('3.0.0.0')

print MinD<= TGood and TGood<=MaxD
print MinD<= TBad  and TBad<=MaxD
```

Comment: Я бы записал константы в шестнадцатеричном виде, тогда было бы видно, что это на самом деле круглые числа, а не какие-то магические константы. Еще лучше было бы сдвиг использовать вместо умножения.

Comment: @insolor так? А то я с телефона поверить не могу)

Comment: да, как вариант.

Answer (score 1):

[В Питоне 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html):

```
>>> from ipaddress import ip_address
>>> netaddr, broadcast = map(ip_address, ["2.0.0.0",  "2.15.255.255"])
>>> netaddr <= ip_address("2.1.0.0") <= broadcast
True
>>> netaddr <= ip_address("3.1.0.0") <= broadcast
False
```

Или:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.summarize_address_range(netaddr, broadcast)
[IPv4Network('2.0.0.0/12')]
>>> from ipaddress import ip_network
>>> ip_address('2.1.0.0') in ip_network('2.0.0.0/12')
True
>>> ip_address('3.1.0.0') in ip_network('2.0.0.0/12')
False
```

[В Питоне 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294427/4279):

```
>>> import socket
>>> import struct
>>> ip2int = lambda ip: struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]
>>> netaddr, broadcast = map(ip2int, ["2.0.0.0",  "2.15.255.255"])
>>> netaddr <= ip2int("2.1.0.0") <= broadcast
True
>>> netaddr <= ip2int("3.1.0.0") <= broadcast
False
```

Или если сеть задана как адрес и маска, то чтобы узнать принадлежит ли заданный адрес сети, можно использовать побитовые операции: [`(ip & netmask) == netaddr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053031/4279):

```
>>> netaddr = ip2int('2.0.0.0')
>>> bits = 12 # /12
>>> netmask = (~0 << (32 - bits)) & 0xffffffff
>>> (ip2int("2.1.0.0") & netmask) == netaddr
True
>>> (ip2int("3.1.0.0") & netmask) == netaddr
False
```